# Android: Prevent fragment from becoming "active" while replacing another

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have the following invocations:

```
context.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(tag.name(), 1);
context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag.name()).addToBackStack(tag.name()).commit();
```

...while I have at least 2 other fragments on the backstack that were opened before. When these two commands will be executed and the latest fragment has been popped off the backstack, for a very short period of time, the fragment before this fragment is going to be active before the popped fragment has been replace by the given one. And that's the problem, because this fragment fetches data from server and is displaying a progress dialog. Sometimes this leads to race conditions and strange behaviour.

How can I prevent the "non-active" fragments from becoming active while replacing another fragment?

Here is a short explanation of the situation:
MainActivity -> opens Fragment1 -> opens Fragment2a -> opens EditActivity -> after "save action", Fragment2a will be popped and a new Fragment2b will be added into the fragment_container of the MainActivity. While this happens, Fragment1 is doing things, but it must not do this. I want to prevent Fragment1 to do any tasks. It should somehow just stay in background and "sleep".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I misuse the fragment manager concept so that this situation can occur or if the fragment manager concept is a total crap (like a lot in Android), but I solved it by using some workaround. When I start or replace a new fragment, I store immediately an ID in the application context. When a Fragment is getting started, it checks if is has the correct id. If not, I return a null view and the fragment won't be created. The check looks like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return FragmentCreationHelper.createFragmentView(inflater, container, TAG, getFragmentId(), R.layout.fragment_mycoolview);
}
```

The helper class...

```
public class FragmentCreationHelper
{
    public static View createFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, String loggingTag, FragmentTag fragmentId, int template)
    {
        Log.d(loggingTag, "onCreateView()");
        if (MyContext.getNextVisibleFragment() == null || fragmentId.equals(MyContext.getNextVisibleFragment()))
        {
            Log.d(loggingTag, "inflating view...");
            return inflater.inflate(template, container, false);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(loggingTag, "Skipping view inflation. Fragment should not be displayed.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using observer pattern? You create an interface with a method to set fragments to busy starte or do some logic.

All fragments implement this interfac and you create a list that contains these interface inside Activity. If a fragment is registered add this fragments to list or remove them with unregister methods for example.

`(MyActivity)getActivity.register(this);` can be called to register a fragment. Or you can call a method like in active fragment if you wish to set other fragments except this one as busy `(MyActivity)getActivity.setActive(this)` and inside MyActivity you can declare this method as

```
public void setActive(IStateController fragment) {
    for(IStateController f: listOfSubscribers) {
        if(f == fragment) {
            // This fragment called the method and should active
            // other fragments can be set to busy or waiting state   
        }
    }
}
```

I really can't say if it works for you but interacting with fragments without being aware of each other can be done this way, or you can check [EventBus library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: I update because the idea led me to a working workaround. I solved it in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Just check

```
if(getActivity() == null || !isAdded){
    return; //don't do your code that touches UI if it is not active.
}
```

but make sure you have your onPause remove your busy indicator then if you don't plan to wait for completion or you will create a memory leak of window leaking.

Comment: This will not work. The fragment in the background is always added to the Activity and `onPause()` in the fragment will only be executed when the (Main-)Activity is going onPause, but this never happens as the app is being closed. I will update my question for better understanding.

Comment: Now I'm definitely confused haha. onPause for the fragment will happen when it is no longer on the screen or replaced by another fragment. This has nothing to do with the Activity. You mentioned that the "fragment is displaying the progress" so why would you not have the ability to remove it onPause? Next you updated your question to say "prevent non-active" fragments from becoming active. Simple, don't use a transaction to make them active ;). Why would you replace with them if you don't want them active. Sounds more like you want a util class of some sort?

Comment: Fragment's `onPause()` will only be called when the Activity is going `onPause()`, so you cannot bind logic to Fragment's `onPause()` when you only take care on Fragment operations.